# Purpose of git checkout

Tags: git

What happens if I accidentally run `git checkout` command?
There is no argument supplied, just git checkout.
I have a git repository. While trying to switch to a different branch, I mistakenly ran `git checkout` rather than `git checkout <branch-name>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing changes: it's "a glorified no-op".
(It may show output, but nothing happens to the repository.)

From `git checkout --help`:

> ```
>     $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```
>
> You could omit `<branch>`, in which case the command degenerates to
>   "check out the current branch", which is a glorified no-op with a
>   rather expensive side-effects to show only the tracking
>   information, if exists, for the current branch.